# Data for producer prices for products

Tags: data-request

I am working with some data that express the environmental byproducts for the manufacturing of specific broad product categories (e.g. milk, soap, leather). The statistics are given per dollar of producer price, e.g. 1$ of soap products results into 0.1kg of CO2 emissions.

I was wondering, where can I find the average producer price for the relevant product categories, so that I can roughly calculate for example how much CO2 emissions are  emitted in average for 100g of soap products?

Comment: It depends a bit on which country you are considering. Different countries have different sources of data for this (if at all).  Also note that the average producer price is going to be a VERY rough estimate given the variation available in production categories

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking at US producer prices then the Bureau of Labor Statistics is where you would go to find the data.  Producer price indexes are here: https://www.bls.gov/ppi/

If you are looking at other countries producer prices then I would recommend  the OECD:  https://data.oecd.org/price/producer-price-indices-ppi.htm

Or this site as well:  https://www.economy.com/indicators/producer-price-index-ppi